# ¿Por qué se devuelve varias veces un valor en este código?

Tags: jquery

Codigoproducto2 me devuelve varias veces un valor.

```
totalventa=0;

$(".agregar").click(function(){

    codigoproducto =$(this).parent().parent().children(".codigoproducto").html();
    nombreproducto =$(this).parent().parent().children(".nombreproducto").html();
    precio = $(this).parent().parent().children(".precio").html();
    cantidad = $(this).parent().parent().children().children(".cantidad").val();
    total=precio*cantidad;
    totalventa=totalventa+total;
    $(".totaltemp").val(totalventa);

    $(".agregarproducto").before(' <tr class="trjson"><th class="codigoproducto">'+codigoproducto+'</th><th class="cantidad">'+cantidad+'</th><th class="nombreproducto">'+nombreproducto+'</th><th class="precio">'+precio+'</th><th class="total">'+total+'</th><th><a href="#" class="eliminardetalle" data-toggle="modal" ><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></th></tr>');

    $(".agregarproducto").html('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>SUBTOTAL $</strong></td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>IVA $</strong></td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>TOTAL $</strong></td><td>'+totalventa+'</td></tr>');

    $(".eliminardetalle").one('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        codigoproducto2=$(this).parent().siblings(".codigoproducto").html();
        console.log(codigoproducto2);
    });


});
```

---

Con `agregar` yo creo un producto en una tabla, y en esa tabla deseo eliminar el producto y efectivamente lo elimina.

Sin embargo, esa variable me devuelve el valor del codigo que elimino.

El producto que agregué de primero me imprime la variable una sola vez si asigno un segundo producto y elimino me devuelve dos veces y asi sucesivamente.

No sé si esto en lo correcto pero pienso que el `before` cuando creo los productos hace algo.

---

```
totalventa=0;


      $(".agregar").click(function(){



    codigoproducto =$(this).parent().parent().children(".codigoproducto").html();
    nombreproducto =$(this).parent().parent().children(".nombreproducto").html();
    precio = $(this).parent().parent().children(".precio").html();
    cantidad = $(this).parent().parent().children().children(".cantidad").val();
    total=precio*cantidad;
    totalventa=totalventa+total;
    $(".totaltemp").val(totalventa);

    $(".agregarproducto").before(' <tr class="trjson"><th class="codigoproducto">'+codigoproducto+'</th><th class="cantidad">'+cantidad+'</th><th class="nombreproducto">'+nombreproducto+'</th><th class="precio">'+precio+'</th><th class="total">'+total+'</th><th><a href="#" class="eliminardetalle" data-toggle="modal" ><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></th></tr>');

    $(".agregarproducto").html('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>SUBTOTAL $</strong></td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>IVA $</strong></td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>TOTAL $</strong></td><td>'+totalventa+'</td></tr>');

});

    $(".trjson").on("click", ".eliminardetalle", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    codigoproducto=$(this).parent().siblings(".codigoproducto").html();
    console.log(codigoproducto);
});
```

De esta manera no borra los productos que asigne con before
agregre trjson que supongo que es un selector cercano

---

Aqui es donde asigno los productos con el before 
la "X" es donde se activa el evento eliminardetalle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><div class="botonmenu">SoftCont</div></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="table-wrapper" class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="table-title">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h3>Nueva Factura</h3>
            </div>

        </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <form method="post">
         <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="form-group">
             <label for="Codigo Factura">Codigo Factura:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="codigofactura"  id="codigofactura" required>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="form-group">
             <label for="Cedula">Cedula:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cedulacliente" id="cedula" required>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="form-group">
             <label for="Nombre">Nombre:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombrevalidar" id="nombre" disabled>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="form-group">
             <label for="Direccion">Direccion:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" disabled>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="form-group">
             <label for="Telefono">Telefono:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telefono" disabled>
            </div>
            </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="form-group">
             <label for="Vendedor">Vendedor:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="selector" name="cedulavendedor" required>
              <option ></option>
              <?php
            $mostrarvendedor = new Factura();
            $mostrarvendedor -> mostrarVendedorController();

            ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="form-group">
             <label for="Fecha">Fecha:</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="date" id="fecha" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" disabled>
            </div>
            </div>
              <input  type="number" id="totaltemp" class="totaltemp" name="totalventa" hidden>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <a href="#addproductomodal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></i><span id="spantitulo">Nuevo Producto</span></a>
                <a href="#addEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></i><span id="spantitulo">Nuevo Cliente</span></a>
                <a href="#addproductodetallemodal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></i><span id="spantitulo">Agregar Productos</span></a>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success guardar" value="Guardar"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <!-- Edit Modal HTML -->
```

Nuevo Cliente
                    ×
                
                                    
                    
                        Cedula
                        
                    
                    
                        Nombres
                        
                    
                    
                        Telefono
                         
                    
                    
                        Direccion
                         
                    
                    
                        Descripcion
                         
                                      
                
                
                    
                    
                
            
        
    







    
        
            
                                      
                    Nuevo Producto
                    ×
                
                                    
                    
                        Codigo Producto
                        
                    
                    
                        Nombre De Producto
                        
                    
                    
                        Precio
                         
                    
                    
                        Cantidad

Agregar Producto
                    ×
                
                 
                
                                   
                    
                    
                      
                        
                            Codigo Producto
                            Nombre De Producto
                            Precio
                            Cantidad
                            Accion
                        
                    
                                 

                               mostrarProductoFacturaController();
                      ?>

guardarClienteFacturaController();
$guardardatosfactura->guardarProductoFacturaController();
$guardardatosfactura->insertarFacturaController();
?>

```
        </br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">   
                  <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Codigo De Producto</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="agregarproducto">

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deberías incluir el HTML necesario para reproducir el problema completo. De esa manera habría un [mcve] y podríamos ver el posible error y ayudarte con más facilidad.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta pulsando en el botón de [edit] en lugar de escribir respuestas para añadir más información.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto es un error de concepto.

Con [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) estás añadiendo un controlador del evento indicado (en este caso `click`) y ese controlador de evento se ejecutará como mucho una vez por elemento y evento. Por eso esperas ver el valor una única vez en la consola.

Pero lo ves varias veces, ¿por qué?

Porque cada vez que pulsas en el botón estás asociando un nuevo controlador del evento al elemento. Y dicho controlador se considera diferente al anterior (que sea la misma función no quiere decir que sea el mismo controlador). Que tenga `one` sólo indica que ese controlador se va a ejecutar una vez; pero si lo asocias múltiples veces, entonces sólo se va a ejecutar una vez... múltiples veces.

Aquí puedes ver un caso similar: pulsa en el botón de añadir eventos varias veces, con cada una de ellas se estará asociando un nuevo controlador, por lo que en la consola verás tantos mensajes como veces hayas pulsado en el botón principal:

```js
$("#principal").click(function() {
  $("#botones button").one("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="principal">Añadir eventos a los otros bottones</button>
</div>
<div id="botones">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>
```

En el caso de la pregunta, cada vez que pulses en el `.agregar` estarás asociando un nuevo controlador del evento `click` a cada `.eliminardetalle` de la página. No sólo al que se acaba de añadir sino a ese y al resto que ya existían en la página.

Una posible solución sería usar una variable centinela para que el botón sólo se ejecute una vez. Pero además de eso, deberías sacar la asociación del controlador de evento fuera del `click` de agregar (para evitar que se asocie múltiples veces) y usar eventos delegados en su lugar:

```js
$("body").on("click", "#botones button", function() {
  if (!this.clicked) {
    this.clicked = true;
    console.log($(this).text());
  }
});

$("#principal").click(function() {
  // otras operaciones sin añadir eventos
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="principal">Añadir eventos a los otros bottones</button>
</div>
<div id="botones">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>
```

También se pueden tener eventos delegados con `.one()` pero son más complejos (en el sentido de que tienen "truco" ya que sólo se ejecutarían una vez por selector), o con `.off()`... pero de nuevo no termina de ser sencillo con eventos delegados.

Comment: Ya lo habia intentado. sacando el evento $(".eliminardetalle") afuera del agregar, pero si lo saco tengo otro inconveniente. no obtiene los html de esta parte   $(".agregarproducto").before(' <tr class="trjson"><th class="codigoproducto">'+codigoproducto+'</th><th class="cantidad">'+cantidad+'</th><th class="nombreproducto">'+nombreproducto+'</th><th class="precio">'+precio+'</th><th class="total">'+total+'</th><th><a href="#" class="eliminardetalle" data-toggle="modal" ><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></th></tr>');

Comment: @AlbertoJulioArceEscolar no se sacaría tal cual. Debes usar eventos delegados como indico en la respuesta. Sería `$("body").on("click", ".eliminardetalle", function() { ... })`

Comment: O preferiblemente, en lugar de `body` el selector más cercano posible para hacerlo más eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia

```
$(".eliminardetalle").one('click', function() {
```

por

```
$(".eliminardetalle").on('click', function() {
```

one hace una llamada por cada elemento que cuadre con el selector, no solo el que cliqueaste.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comentas suele pasar cuando referencias varias veces el mismo archivo script. O porque el evento que lanza la acción esté dentro de una función lo que hace que vaya duplicando con cada pasada la acción.

Además de arrelgar el fallo del .one que comenta mi compañero de arriba